# Technique to force MySQL's GROUP BY to produce a result for an empty group?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that applies MySQL’s GROUP BY function to count the number of events that occurred on a given session.  The sessions increase in increments of 1.  So, the result may look like this.

```
session events
100     10
101     15
102     29
103     15
104     2
```

A problem arises when there aren’t any events in a given session.  So, imagine that, instead of containing 29 observations in session 102, there are 0.  The results look like this.

```
session events
100     10
101     15
103     15
104     2
```

What technique would force GROUP BY to recognize the 0 events in session 102, and have the results look like this? I.e, report session 102 with 0 events.

```
session events
100     10
101     15
102     0
103     15
104     2
```

Comment: You should post the sql query to help people help you.

Comment: Show us your current query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could LEFT JOIN to another table which contains all the sessions you are interested in. By using LEFT JOIN, you'd ensure that all the results from the 'other' table ends up in the results.

e.g. for a `source` table:

> ```
> >    SOURCE_SESSION
> >     100
> >     101
> >     102
> >     103
> >     104
> >     ...
> ```

you'd write something like

```
SELECT SOURCE_SESSION, sum(events)
FROM   source
LEFT JOIN my_table on source.SOURCE_SESSION = my_table.session
GROUP BY source.SOURCE_SESSION
```

Your mileage may vary, but that's the general idea.

Comment: Thx Ryan,  This is similar to a solution I've started considering. I was wondering if I was missing something really obvious that would make it a bit easier.  Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Without the schema or current query this is speculation.

Assuming you have two tables one with sessions and the other events. You can `LEFT JOIN` sessions to events to include sessions with no events. Now when you group by session id and count up the events, you will get your result including sessions with zero events.